# Get platform type of Ec2 Instances

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am using describe_instance_information() from [BOTO 3 Link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_instance_information) to get the platform type of the instance but I am getting the empty response [image: Response Output]

this is my code:

```
import boto3
import time
import json

ssm= boto3.client('ssm',aws_access_key_id='*****',aws_secret_access_key='*****', region_name='us-east-1')
response= ssm.describe_instance_information(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Key': 'InstanceIds',
            'Values': [
                'i-instanceId'
            ]
        },
    ]
)
print response
```

is there any other solution where i can fetch the platform type of Ec2 Instance.

Comment: ssm is meant to work only with [managed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/managed_instances.html) instances

Answer (score 1):

You're using boto3 SSM client, which will only work if you have SSM installed and is registered by the instance. You can better user [ec2.describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) for the same. This returns 'windows' if platform is windows, blank otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'aws ssm describe-instance-information help'

> The following describe-instance-information example  shows  details  of
>        the managed instance i-028ea792daEXAMPLE.
>
> ```
>  aws ssm describe-instance-information --filters "Key=InstanceIds,Values=i-028ea792daEXAMPLE"
> ```

one can understand that this feature is restricted only to *managed* instances.